# For loop does not increase i

Tags: javascript

In my example count = 2. The first one works fine, but why does the second one not work? i equals 0 for all loops, so it become an infinite loop and crashes my browser tab.

I am not new to javascript but didn't encounter that problem before. The only explanation I can think of, is that in for loop it is not possible to increase the counting value by more than 1. But it does not make sense to me.

```
for (i = 0; i < count * 3; i++){
    console.log(i);
};
```

Result : 0,1,2,3,4,5

```
for (i = 0; i < count * 3; i+3){
    console.log(i);
};
```

Result: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your increment is

```
i+3
```

...which doesn't do anything to write back to `i`. To write back, use `i+=3`:

```
for (i = 0; i < count * 3; i+=3){
```

The `+=` operator adds the right-hand side to the left-hand side *and* stores the result in the left-hand side. The `+` operator just does the addition, without storing the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < count * 3; i+=3){
    console.log(i);
};
```

Comment: missed the ++ in the code above and fixed it. But that's not my current problem.

Comment: And that's it? Not a word of explanation?